# CASE in a SELECT Statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table and I would like to have a select statement that selects VALUE based on a given code. 
CASE statement might be needed, but all examples I looked at so far had distinct values as a result of the case.

TABLE A

```
ID      ||    VALUE 
1       ||    value1 
2       ||    value2 
3       ||    value3 
4       ||    value4 
5       ||    value5 
6       ||    value3 
7       ||    value2 
8       ||    value8
```

TABLE B

```
ID         ||CODE 
1          ||1    
2          ||2    
3          ||3    
4          ||4    
5          ||1    
6          ||2    
7          ||3    
8          ||4    


SELECT B.CODE,
         CASE 
          WHEN B.CODE = '01' THEN A.value based on code 
          WHEN B.CODE = '02' THEN A.value based on code 
          WHEN B.CODE = '03' THEN A.value based on code 
          WHEN B.CODE = '04' THEN A.value based on code  
          END AS VALUE_OUT
          FROM  A  JOIN  B
                ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Comment: By "table"  do you mean an actual database table or a hypothetical table?  What value should 1 map to?  value1 or value5?

Comment: 1 could map to both values. This is a hypothetical table, but I have similar database table with couple million records in it. There are basically 4 codes that can map to the VALUE fields.

Comment: Are you saying you want to see all of the distinct CODE/VALUE pairs in your table of millions of records?

Comment: Yes, if possible using plain SQL rather than PLSQL.

Comment: In other words, the select statement takes in an input, then it selects the mapped value to it. I'm working on modifying the question to make more sense.

Comment: Question has been modified.

Comment: It looks like you need a `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

You may just need a `WHERE` clause

```
Select Value
From MyTable
Where Code = 1
```

**EDIT**

It looks like an `INNER JOIN` may suffice:

```
SELECT B.Code, A.Value as Value_Out
From A
Inner Join B
    On A.ID = B.Code
```

Comment: This would help if I only had 10-15 records, but I actually have couple million recs to apply the CASE to.

Comment: INNER JOIN would give the value of A.VALUE regardless. However, I need this value based on B.CODE as VALUE_OUT will be used in various tables based on the code and ID it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want just

```
SELECT DISTINCT
code, value
FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT
value
FROM MyTable
WHERE code = 1
```

If you want all values for a particular code.